# Trouble Booting GalliumOS

Tags: boot, dual-boot, chrome-book

Alright, so I have galliumOS installed on a chromebook, and everything works great, except whenever the laptop is put into sleep mode, powered off etc, it takes me back to the OS verification screen. Pressing ctrl + L (which usually boots gallium) doesn't do much of anything, except make a loud beeping sound. Ctrl + D still boots to chromeOS just fine.

I did some looking around and found the following from MrChromebox.tech

```
cd; curl -LO mrchromebox.tech/firmware-util.sh
sudo install -Dt /usr/local/bin -m 755 firmware-util.sh
sudo firmware-util.sh
```

Running this in chromeOS allows me to restart and use ctrl + L to boot to gallium, but only once. After that, I have to go through the process again.

Running `cd; curl -LO mrchromebox.tech/firmware-util.sh && sudo bash firmware-util.sh` once I'm in gallium doesn't seem to do the trick either.

Overall, it's not a huge deal, I'm not planning on using the chromebook all that often, but I'd really prefer to be able to boot more quickly (and without an internet connection)

I might be missing something obvious here, but regardless, any help is appreciated greatly :)